# how to convert normalized frequency to actual frequency

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectrum

suppose that we have following code

```
function [ x ] = generate1(N,m,A3)
f1 = 100;
f2 = 200;
T = 1./f1;
t = (0:(N*T/m):(N*T))'; %'
wn = randn(length(t),1); %zero mean variance 1
x = 20.*sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t) + 30.*cos(2.*pi.*f2.*t) + A3.*wn;
%[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
 plot(x)
end
```

i have generated signal using following command

```
y=generate1(3,500,1);
```

and i have got 501  length sample,now i want to use  music method to detect frequencies,namely 100 and 200,assume that number of  parameter is 2,so i have tried

```
pmusic(y,4)
```

[image]

how  determine actually frequencies from this picture?i think that i need to convert a from normalized  frequency to actual frequency,as i know normalized frequency is same as $f/f_s$ where $f_s$ is sampling frequency,but in this case what i should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to multiply by half the sampling rate. I.e., the normalized frequency "1.0" is Fsample/2.

For a simple example, here's a 200 Hz signal sampled at 4KHz:

```
x=sin(2*pi*200/4000*[0:1000])
```

Running `pmusic(x, 2)` gives a pronounced peak at the normalized frequency 0.1.
Converted to Hz, this is 0.1*4000/2 = 200 Hz.

I have modified your function to make it easier to analyze (just one sine function and no randomness):

```
 function x = gen(N,m)
    f1 = 100;
    T  = 1/f1;
    dt = N*T/m;

    x = sin(2*pi*f1*dt*[0:num_of_samples]);
 end

 x = gen(3,500,1e3);
```

To get better resolution use `pmusic(x,2,[0:.01:0.2])`.

Comment: thanks very much,in my case  what i  should do?let us assume that N=3 and m=500

Comment: but why 0.1?in my case  sampling frequency is 16666.66666666667,so i should have 0.1*16666.66666666667/2 ?

Comment: are you here?i can't continue

Comment: in my picture  peak it not indicated at exact normalized frequency,should i guess?

Comment: In your case the estimated frequency will be Fs/2*0.116 = 1.666e3/2 * 0.116 = 96 Hz. If you take more samples you can get better accuracy. You expect peaks at 100 Hz and 200 Hz (f1 and f2)

Comment: how much do i need to increase sample?what is recomended?

Comment: how did you get  0.116 by the way?

Comment: i have sampled at exactly  at 400 sample rate and get exact peaks,so what does it means?

Comment: what if i dont know sampled frequency?can i calculate frequencies?

Comment: @datodatuashvili added a simpler example

Comment: thanks for help,i am interested now if i dont know sampling frequency and actual frequency,can i calculate from normalized frequency?

Comment: You must know the sampling frequency to get an estimate of the true frequency.